# Column name int cannot be selected

Tags: mysql, sql

I've downloaded a source with a lot of code and tables, in one of the tables I got a column named "int" (The source is big and changing the column name isn't the solution for me).

Anyway, I can't print the data on my website because of the column name! Any other column in the table works except the column 'int'. It tells me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'int FROM characters WHERE id = '30005'' at line 1]

I tried to select it like this:

```
"SELECT int FROM characters WHERE id = '" + userId + "'";
```

And I tried like this:

```
string selectIntSql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                       WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'moopledev' AND TABLE_NAME = 'characters' AND ORDINAL_POSITION = 11";

string selectInt = SqlConnector.printData(selectIntSql);
"SELECT " + selectInt + " FROM characters WHERE id = '" + userId + "'";
```

Nothing worked.
Any idea what to do?

Comment: Hi, just wanted to introduce (again...) my good friend: [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: To use a reserved word in a query string you need to escape the reserved word using \`INT` instead of int.. @alfasin great reference to great laughs..but not really an answer unless he asked about sqli

Comment: @apesa in addition to sanitizing your code any language has a mechanism to properly parameterized sql-queries and using it is a good practice. Concatenating string is bad...

Comment: @alfasin very true, but the OP is obviously new enough that he is asking a very basic question regarding a column named int and how to use it. In the long run he should be using PreparedStatments but in the short run he needs to walk first.Like I said, great site that xkcd.. I even upvoted your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL (any SQL) contains reserved words, which you better not use as a column name. INT is a very obvious one.

The way around this is:

- Use a better column name
- or use backticks around your column

Example for the backticks:

```
 `int`
```

Comment: Option #1 is really the only way to go here. Naming your column so obviously reserved as `INT` is bound to make you look like you're not even sure what SQL is. Be nice to your DBA, especially if that DBA is you!

Comment: To be more accurate, the dumbness is not due to forgetting the backtick, it's due to using a reserved word. But as it always happens, you're not going to listen cause all that matters to you is to "make it work" and when you'll pay dearly later on you won't even remember the warnings that you received here. Oh well...

Answer (score 3):

[int](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) is a keyword, so you must escape it with backticks.

```
"SELECT `int` FROM characters WHERE id = '" + userId + "'";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use reserved Keywords as Column or Table Names 
you must quote them with backticks like this:

```
"SELECT `int` FROM characters WHERE id = '" + userId + "'";
```